# How to use Fastlane and Crashlytics to build while using Xcode automatic code signing?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, crashlytics, fastlane

We can archive build on Xcode and distribute via Crashlytics Beta via the Fabric desktop app; however, the fastlane distribution fails. The build uploads but the testers are not able to install it. Below is part of the Fastfile.

```
build_app(scheme: "The-App-Fabric",
          workspace: "The-App.xcworkspace",
          configuration: "QA",
          output_directory: "./build",
          clean: true,
          include_bitcode: false)
crashlytics(api_token: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            build_secret: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            ipa_path:"./build/The-App-Fabric.ipa",
            groups: ["ios-qa"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspection of the .ipa via [ProvisionQL](https://github.com/ealeksandrov/ProvisionQL) reveals that build_app was automatically choosing the wrong provisioning profile. Specifying `export_team_id` and `export_method` solves the issue. Find your team id [here](https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership).

```
        build_app(scheme: "The-App-Fabric",
            workspace: "The-App.xcworkspace",
            configuration: "QA",
            output_directory: "./build",
            clean: true,
            export_team_id: "XXXXXXXXXX",
            export_method: "development",
            include_bitcode: false)
        crashlytics(api_token: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                build_secret: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                ipa_path:"./build/The-App-Fabric.ipa",
                groups: ["ios-qa"])
```